# delete specific item from an array in localstorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am trying to use the splice() to delete a specific item in an array stored in local storage. but when I click the delete button, all it does is delete the item from the page but not from local storage. How do I solve this?

```js
let localStorageKey = 'userArray';
if (localStorage.getItem(localStorageKey) === null) {
  userArray = [];
} 
else {
  userArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(localStorageKey));
}
userArray.forEach((name) => {
  const para   = document.querySelector('p');
  const delBtn = document.querySelector('.delBtn');
  let delTitem = userArray.splice(name, 1);
  delBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    para.textContent = '';
    localStorage.removeItem(delTitem);
  });
  para.innerHTML = `${name.firstname} ${name.lastname}`;
```

Comment: 1. .splice() changes an array in place; I don't think your approach is a good idea; I personally would use a unique id to identify the item and use `.filter()` to remove it. 2. the item is not removed from localStorage because you never call `.setItem` to update it anywhere.

Comment: @Chris G  **the item is not removed from localStorage because you never call .setItem anywhere**, do they have to call `setItem` for it to be removed? It may have been set before.

Comment: @Countour-Integral `.getItem` reads the string stored there, it does not return a reference to an object you can change. In order to update the stored array, you have to stringify it and store it using `.setItem`

Comment: @Chris G My bad, forgot the question was specific to Objects.

Comment: @Countour-Integral Doesn't matter; it's the same for strings. Reading one from LS and updating the variable does nothing to the stored string either (even in theory this won't work because afaik strings are immutable, so you'd lose the reference anyway)

Comment: @Chris G I did not mean  that this way, you can remove a string from localStorage by using `localStorage.removeItem`, but as you said you can't do this with Objects, they are stored as raw text in `localStorage` and you will have to parse them to update their keys.

Comment: @Ekankam it would help if you showed us what your `JSON` actually looks like.

Answer (score 1):

I was faced with this same issue, I was encouraged to check @stackoverflow, when I read this post I got a cleared insight  on how to delete a specific item in a localstorage with js using foreach loop Here is my code working as I expected it work:

```
let keys = {"values" : []};

function deleteTask(delButton, taskName) {

    delButton.addEventListener("click", ()=>{

 keys.values.forEach((item, index)=>{

  if(item === taskName){
      keys.values.splice(index, 1);
      localStorage.setItem("tasks", keys values);
     }
   });
```

});
}

@Ekankam, @Chris G...

Answer (score 0):

Try re-storing the item by `stringify`ing it once more, and calling `.setItem` should so the trick if the rest of your code is working for you. Then it will save your new array without the deleted value into the `localStorage`